# What is "alt mode"?

Tags: reus

I was looking at some of the advanced options in Reus and it indicated that some of them enable "alt mode". What is "alt mode"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt mode disables some of the achievements for the game. It's meant for when using these options would make it easier to get those achievements than they're meant to be.

Comment: I have been unlocking items in alt mode that clearly state you can't use alt mode. Why?